# partial differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the pde $$\  \dfrac {\partial u}{\partial t} + \ 3\dfrac {\partial u}{\partial x}=0.$$

$$ x>0, t>0$$

$$u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}, x>0,$$ $$ u(0,t) = e^{-t^2}, t>0 $$

The characteristics are given by $x(t)=3t + \eta $

I must then parameterise the initial values, and the solution to this problem says we have 
$$ x_0(\eta)=\eta,$$ $$t_0(\eta)=0,$$ $$u_0(\eta) = exp(-\eta^2),$$ $$\eta>0 $$

What i need to know is how did we get these values? I know this is probably a very stupid question but i learnt this nearly a year ago and all feels a bit muddled, i have an exam on this next week and thought that i could do these with no problem but actually i cant remember and cannot find any useful resources. Could someone please explain in easy steps? I dont need the full solution to the problem as i have it here, i would just like to know how to paramaterise this pde.

Many thanks

Comment: A subscripted $0$ means that $t=0$. i.e. $u_0(\eta)=u(\eta,0)$ and $x_0(\eta)$ is the value of $x$ at $t=0$.

Comment: Your BC is not consistent with IC. Linear advection equation
$$
u_t + a u_x = 0
$$
has a solution
$$
u(x,t) = u_0(x-at)
$$
So, in your case
$$
u(x,t) = u_0(x-3t)\\
u(x,0) = u_0(x) = e^{-x^2}
$$
and therefore
$$
u(x,t) = e^{-(x-3t)^2}
$$
If you want to find BC just substitute $x = 0$ to the solution
$$
u(0,t) = e^{-9t^2}
$$
which is not equal to what you provided.

Comment: but this must be correct as it is part of solutions for the question... are you sure?

Comment: i know what $$t_0$$ means, but how did they get one of the initial conditions as 0 and one as $$\eta$$ ? i just dont see how they have done this

Comment: @user67411 where did you get that solution? Usually, for linear advection equation BC is redundant, and solution is driven by IC, basically IC just moves right or left with the speed $a$.

Comment: solution from my practice exam paper! its a cauchy pde characteristic equation, solved by method of cauchy characteristics!